# SimpleXML Element & Inline Elementlist Random Order

Tags: java, android, xml, simple-framework

I have three different message pojos to be parsed as XML with the SimpleXML lib on an android app. The first pojo:

```
@Root(name = "Message")
public class InventoryMessage {

    @Element(name = "Header")
    private Header header;

    @ElementList(inline = true)
    private ArrayList<InventoryBarcode> inventoryData;

    public InventoryMessage(ArrayList<InventoryBarcode> inventoryData) {
        this.header = new Header(ScanSource.INVENTORY);
        this.inventoryData = inventoryData;
    }

}
```

Parses the message just the way I'd like it to:

```
<Message>
   <Header>
      <DateTime></DateTime>
      <HospitalCode></HospitalCode>
      <MessageType></MessageType>
   </Header>
   <InventoryData>
      <EventDtm></EventDtm>
      <ItemCode></ItemCode>
      <UserCode></UserCode>
      <LocationCode></LocationCode>
   </InventoryData>
</Message>
```

However when I do exactly the same with this one:

```
@Root(name = "Message")
public class CyclecountMessage {

    @Element(name = "Header")
    private Header header;

    @ElementList(inline = true)
    private ArrayList<CyclecountBarcode> cyclecountData;

    public CyclecountMessage(ArrayList<CyclecountBarcode> cyclecountData) {
        this.header = new Header(ScanSource.CYCLECOUNT);
        this.cyclecountData = cyclecountData;
    }
}
```

I get:

```
<Message>
   <CyclecountData>
      <EventDtm></EventDtm>
      <ItemCode></ItemCode>
      <UserCode></UserCode>
      <LocationCode></LocationCode>
   </CyclecountData>
   <Header>
      <DateTime></DateTime>
      <HospitalCode></HospitalCode>
      <MessageType></MessageType>
   </Header>
</Message>
```

No matter what I try the order stays the same. The inventory places the Header on top and the other two (one of which you see here) keeps placing the header on the bottom. What is causing this? I have tried adding @Order but no luck since @ElementList is not a real @Element I guess, no idea.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: it is always in alphabetical order (I after H, C before H)

Comment: @AsierAranbarri Thanks that clears up alot of confusion. Do you happen to also know a way to change this behaviour?

Comment: haha really not, just took a look and observed that